# нет vuejs в package.json

Tags: laravel, vue.js, package.json

Если верить документации laravel, то из коробки у него в package.json должен быть VueJS. Но я такого там не обнаружил.
Посмотрел в двух проектах laravel 8.9, одинаково.
Это какое-то нововведение или при установке что-то пошло не так?

Comment: а где вы искали?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру в корневом файле package.json. Там должен был быть прописан vue, но по стоку его нет

Comment: а нужно искать в `vendor` т.к пакет `laravel/ui` имеет зависимость от vue js в СВОЕМ package.json

Answer (score 0):

Уже не помню точно, но вроде бы с 7-й версии laravel уже не идет по дефолту с vuejs и пакетом auth.
Чтобы появился vuejs и пакет auth нужно выполнить шаги описанные в документации
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

Тут вы сможете выбрать что использовать vue или react

Comment: попробовал на 8 версии, не сработало